# unfortunately <app name feedback> has stopped. (android studio) when insatll

Tags: android

My app stopped working. Here is the error stack trace
[image]

And this is what the app shows
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to an image you are trying import in your project..... how about putting some of your code along with logs...

Comment: <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgView_passwordIcon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/phn"
                    android:tint="@color/white" />

Comment: <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgView_passwordIcon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/phn"
                    android:tint="@color/white" />

Comment: PROBLM IN IMGE VIEW

Comment: i cannot help you without log.... upload full logs...along with full code of both xml and java file.. edit it in the question you asked above, so that more people can help you :)

Comment: my phone don't accept my image view code

Comment: In your android studio.....there is log tab at bottom of the screen ....when you experience error it shows all logs and  errors

Comment: storage refrence null error